# Confirming Test Credit Card Transactions via Merchant Servicess

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We are submitting test cc credit card transaction to the test QBMS gatewey and would like to verify they are being submitted correctly. We are getting what looks like the correct response valid response to the submittal but nothing is showing up in the merchant service center for the past month. Is this correct, i.e., the test service center is hit or miss or is it failing somewhere else? Even items we submit through the test page do not show up in the service center. Thanks.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Test transactions do not show anything in the GUI.

Comment: So items never show up on this page [link](http://merchantcenter.ptcfe.intuit.com/qbms.)?

Comment: The GUI components of test/ptc accounts DO NOT WORK. If you're using the test servers, nothing will ever show up in the GUI "Service Center" area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the TEST tool here, it is posting the transaction under a test account not your account, so you see the successful response, but you would only see the transaction if you logged in under the test account, which is not possible as its simply for testing.

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/030_qbms/0030_Get_Set_Up/5._Try_a_Test_Transaction

thanks
Jarred

Comment: That makes sense but on the page listed above there is a [link](http://merchantcenter.ptcfe.intuit.com/qbms.). It appears that things occasionally show up there, for instance there is one transaction from the other day, but only one. Thanks.